# How can I get Apache to use PHP 7.0 (not 7.1)?

Tags: 16.04, apache2, php

When setting up a Ubuntu 16.04 vhost, Apache will use
**PHP 7.0.22-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4**.

However, after trying to resolve some conflicts by doing `apt-get dist-upgrade` (and failing), I ended up with a badly broken system. I've  since managed to roll back most package versions to those that are default, but Apache uses 
**PHP 7.1.8-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4**, which is incompatible with some PHP-libraries I need.

So far, I've tried:

```
sudo a2dismod php7.1
sudo a2enmod php7.0
sudo service apache2 restart
```

However, this breaks Apache and it refuses to restart:

```
Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.0.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.0.so
```

How can I get Apache to run the default PHP version (PHP 7.0) again?

**Edit**: A comment to my [now redacted] self-answer below by *Dan*  made me realize that having added the following third party PPA `ppa:ondrej/php` may have something do do with the problem.

So:
I have added the PPA `ppa:ondrej/php` to my site.

Comment: You can try to reinstall he module: `sudo apt install --reinstall libapache2-mod-php7.0`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll split my answer into two parts. The first part describes how your problem occurred, the second part is the actual answer to your issue.

#### Description

<sup>*Disclaimer: Most of my description is basically speculation, as I cannot really know what you did. But it's the most likely scenario, as I cannot think of another way that would end up giving you the issue you described.*</sup>

From the problem you describe, it seems you have installed a third party PPA which installed PHP 7.1 on your system. The most likely PPA is [Ondrej's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php).

When you first installed PHP, you installed in the following method:

```
sudo apt install php
```

The `php` package is only a meta package and does not contain the binaries needed. It depends on the latest version of the available PHP package (by default 7.0). So when you install it, the `php7.0` package is installed along with `php7.0`'s dependencies (and `libapache2-mod-php7.0`
 if you have `apache2`) and all those dependencies are marked in the package manager as "automatically installed".

```
$ apt show php
Package: php
Version: 1:7.0+35ubuntu6
Priority: optional
Section: php
Source: php-defaults (35ubuntu6)
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers 
Original-Maintainer: Debian PHP Maintainers 
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 11.3 kB
Depends: php7.0
Supported: 5y
Download-Size: 2,832 B
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Description: server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (default)
 PHP (recursive acronym for PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor) is a widely-used
 open source general-purpose scripting language that is especially suited
 for web development and can be embedded into HTML.
 .
 This package is a dependency package, which depends on Debian's default
 PHP version (currently 7.0).
```

I bolded the parts of the command's result, which explains what I just mentioned.

Ondrej's PHP PPA offers multiple PHP versions that can be installed alongside each other. So when you added it your system, `apt` found a newer version of PHP so it replaced `php7.0`* with `php7.1` along with any related packages that were automatically installed.

#### Answer

There are two methods to fix your issues.

1. Completely remove the 3rd party PPA, and revert back to the default PHP packages

   ```
   sudo apt install ppa-purge
   sudo ppa-purge ppa:ondrej/php
   ```
2. Ondrej's PPA offers multiple versions of PHP, so you can install more than one version along side each other. But you would enable only the `php7.0` Apache module.

   ```
   sudo apt install php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0
   sudo a2dismod php7.1
   sudo a2enmod php7.0
   sudo apache2ctl restart
   ```

   Installing them in the previous manner would set the `php7.0` package as "manually installed" in `apt`, so they won't get removed automatically without you removing them yourself.
   *Don't forget to make sure to install any PHP modules you need for php7.0 as well (Like `sudo apt install php7.0-mysql`)*

* `php7.0` may have been kept in your system installed if you had manually installed a module specifically for php7.0 (for example `php7.0-mysql`).

Comment: I went for solution 1 (completely remove the 3rd party PPA). Then I purged and reinstalled PHP 7.0 from the offical sources. Things are now back to normal.Thanks a lot!

Comment: `libapache2-mod-php7.0` was missing after compiling Apache from source. Running `apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0` solved this for me.

Comment: Method 1 did it's magic! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By searching [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=exactfilename&suite=yakkety&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libphp7.0.so&searchon=contents) for the file `libphp7.0`, I found two packages containing that file. Is either or both installed?  `libapache2-mod-php7.0` and/or `libphp7.0-embed`?

Reinstalling `libapache2-mod-php7.0` with

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

then see what there is to read in the package. List the contents with

```
dpkg -L libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

The search results:

```
 » Ubuntu » Packages » Package Contents Search Results

    Search for libphp7.0.so within filenames
    Search for paths ending with libphp7.0.so 

Search in other suite: [trusty] [xenial] [yakkety] [zesty] [artful]

Limit search to a specific architecture: [amd64] [arm64] [armhf] [i386] [powerpc] [ppc64el] [s390x]

You have searched for files named libphp7.0.so in suite yakkety, all sections, and all architectures. Found 2 results.
File    Packages
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.0.so   libapache2-mod-php7.0
/usr/lib/libphp7.0.so   libphp7.0-embed
```