# Ubuntu 17.10 Use PHP7.0 instead of PHP7.1

Tags: 17.10, php7

I have both php7.1 and php7.0 installed on my **ubuntu 17.10**. When I type `php -v`, the result shows PHP 7.1.8-1buntu1 (cli). However I have a project that doesn't support php 7.1, so I need to downgrade it to php 7.0.

I have tried the following, which didn't work.

```
sudo a2dismod php7.1
sudo a2enmod php7.0
sudo service apache2 restart
```

This answer does not help since it's a solution for ubuntu 16.04, and i'm using 17.10
[How can I get Apache to use PHP 7.0 (not 7.1)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/944036/how-can-i-get-apache-to-use-php-7-0-not-7-1)

Comment: did you check for any errors in the apache2 log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

The following way is to switch PHP version for Apache.

```
sudo a2dismod php7.1
sudo a2enmod php7.0
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And for switching PHP version for Command Line, we need this,

```
update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.0
```